# How to hide and display item templates in formview depending on some conditions?

Tags: asp.net, session, formview

Here I am getting  some  values from previous page using session to check the condition:

```
  string PTN = Session["PrimaryTool"].ToString();
  string PTE = Session["PrimaryToolExp"].ToString();
  if (PTN != null && PTE != null)
  {
     if (fvJobApplying.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
     {
         Label PT = (Label)fvJobApplying.FindControl("lblPrimaryTool");
         PT.Visible = true;

         Label PTExperience = (Label)fvJobApplying.FindControl("lblPrimaryToolExp");
         PTExperience.Visible = true;
         Label Experience = (Label)fvJobApplying.FindControl("lblExperience");
         Experience.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

My session values and my condition works fine... Here depending on condition how to show and hide columns or item templates in formview in asp.net

Comment: So what's the problem? In general you should use `FormView`'s `DataBound` event formt this.

Comment: What is your question? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what problem/error you actually have, however...

Don't use `Page_Load` to bind or access your `FormView`, instead use the `FormView`'s `DataBound` event and the [`CurrentMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.currentmode.aspx):

```
protected void fvJobApplying_DataBound(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(fvJobApplying.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
    {
        // here you can safely access the FormView's ItemTemplate and it's controls via FindControl
        Label PT = (Label)fvJobApplying.FindControl("lblPrimaryTool");
        PT.Visible = true;
    }
    else if(fvJobApplying.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        // here  you can safely access the FormView's EditItemTemplate and it's controls via FindControl
    }
    else if(fvJobApplying.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
        // here you can safely access the FormView's InsertItemTemplate and it's controls via FindControl
    }
}
```

So find your labels there and set the desired `Visibility`. This event is triggered when you `DataBind` the `FormView.`

Comment: VB version can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710259/hide-label-in-formview-asp-net