# Hide label in Formview ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label, show-hide

I have a "Banned" field in the formview. If the value of this field in false I want to hide the label "From" and "To".

Item template control:

```
<asp:Label ID="BannedCheckBox" runat="server" Text='<%# DisplayTruthValue(Eval("Banned").ToString())%>' /> &nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="BannedFromLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "From: " + Eval("BannedFrom")%>'  />&nbsp;
<asp:Label ID="BannedToLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "To: " + Eval("BannedTo")%>' />
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub FrmViewPatron_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FrmViewPatron.DataBound
Dim blnBan As String = DirectCast(FrmViewPatron.FindControl("BannedCheckBox"), Label).Text
If blnBan = "False" Then

End If
```

Comment: Does the "Banned" field `runat=server`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

You are already databinding the label so why not set the Visible property the same way. Add `Visible='<%# (Eval("Banned") == "True") %>'` to both labels, or just `Eval("Banned")` if it is a boolean field.

Comment: Malk and Yuriy, Thank you for the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
If blnBan = "False" Then
    FrmViewPatron.FindControl("BannedFromLabel").Visible = False
    FrmViewPatron.FindControl("BannedToLabel").Visible = False
End if
```